# Ignoring Aspectj during junit tests

Tags: spring, aspectj

Here is situation:

1. We have class with defined aspect to it's methodA;
2. We have JUnit test for this methodA;

When I run JUnit test it activates Aspect as well. Any thoughts how to ignore Aspects during unit tests?

I have separated tests for my Aspects and it works fine. So in my unit test I want to test only methodA without any attached aspects.

I use spring 3.0 and its aspectj support.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Max

Comment: Is it possible in your testing scenario to use a separate applicationContext for these particular tests, so that you can comment out the AspectJ support from this context?

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I have aspect-it-config for my Aspect IT test, but I don't want to create another version for JUnit test just to turn weaving off. I'll try solution from Espen and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the compile-time weaving that I assume your IDE is doing and use load-time weaving in your separated AspectJ tests.

To enable load-time weaving you have to provide a javaagent as an JVM parameter.

An example:

```
-javaagent:lib/spring-dependencies/spring-agent.jar
```

**Other changes when you move from compile-time to load-time weaving**

You must also provide an aop.xml file in the META-INF folder on the claspath. 
For my trace example, it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in this package -->
        <include within="aspects.trace.demo.*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- use only this aspect for weaving -->
        <aspect name="aspects.trace.TraceAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

In this configuration you can see that the TraceAspect class will be weaved with all the classes in the demo package.

Spring configuration with load-time weaving

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="traceAspect" class="aspects.trace.TraceAspect" 
        factory-method="aspectOf"/>

    <context:load-time-weaver />
</beans>
```

The configuration file is almost the same as the compile-time configuration file, except it also contains a load-time weaver element.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Espen, will give it a go today

Comment: Just thought about it and not sure if it works. The classA and AspectForClassA for weaving is the same. When I run Aspect IT I do need weaving as well as for application run. When I run JUnit I don't. So how can I specify in configuration that weaving must be ignored but only for JUnit tests

Comment: You should refactor your code and have the aspect logic in a separate class. With my suggestion above you will have no weaving by default. You have to provide the javaagent as an JVM argument everytime you need it. If you have automatic compile-time weaving like the Eclipse AJDT plugin gives you, you have to first disable the AspectJ nature on your project.

Comment: Why is the aspect-class referenced in both aop.xml and the Spring context?